# Using Where and Count from Multiply tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

Problem

Columns: Patient_NO, Encounter_Date, Diagnosis_1, Diagnosis_2

Procedure

Columns: Patient_NO, Procedure_Code

I am trying to count the number of unique clients that have a specific diagnosis from the problem table and also a specific procedure from the procedure table.

I'm using the where as an inner join on the two, but when i run the query the count is a bigger number than if i just counted the clients with the specific Diagnosis, which I think is wrong.

```
select (select  COUNT(DIAGNOSIS_1) From Problem, Procedure  where problem.PATIENT_NO=procedure.PATIENT_NO and problem.ENCOUNTER_DATE between '10/1/15' and '12/31/15' and problem.DIAGNOSIS_1 IN ( 'Z68.53', 'Z68.54', 'O99.210', 'E66.9', 'E66.3') and Procedure.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ( 'TS141', 'TS140')) 
 + (select  COUNT(Diagnosis_2) From Problem, Procedure  where problem.PATIENT_NO=Procedure.PATIENT_NO and problem.ENCOUNTER_DATE between '10/1/15' and '12/31/15' and problem.DIAGNOSIS_2 IN ( 'Z68.53', 'Z68.54', 'O99.210', 'E66.9', 'E66.3') and Procedure.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ( 'TS141', 'TS140'))
```

Comment: do you have a third table called patient?

Comment: I do not have a third table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to count how may patient_no meet the specific criteria this might work for you.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pbm.Patient_NO)
FROM   Problem pbm
    JOIN [Procedure] pdr ON pbm.Patient_NO = pdr.Patient_NO
WHERE  pbm.ENCOUNTER_DATE BETWEEN '10/1/15'
                            AND     '12/31/15'
    AND (pbm.DIAGNOSIS_1 IN ('Z68.53','Z68.54','O99.210','E66.9','E66.3')
            OR pbm.DIAGNOSIS_2 IN ('Z68.53','Z68.54','O99.210','E66.9','E66.3'))
    AND pdr.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ('TS141','TS140')
```

Comment: Would you know if it was possible to count the procedure_code column if it had say the TS141 and TS140, but they were in different rows? Like there would be two rows, with the same patient no, and if in one row was TS141 and the other row was TS140, then the count would increase by 1? (if that explains it better)

Comment: It's possible.. just might require a separate query to get the separate counts and combine them.. i'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then you might looking for this -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(pr.Patient_NO)
FROM Problem
INNER JOIN [Procedure] pr
    ON problem.PATIENT_NO = pr.PATIENT_NO
WHERE pr.ENCOUNTER_DATE BETWEEN '10/1/15' AND '12/31/15'
AND (
   pr.DIAGNOSIS_1 IN ('Z68.53', 'Z68.54', 'O99.210', 'E66.9', 'E66.3')
   AND pr.DIAGNOSIS_2 IN ('Z68.53', 'Z68.54', 'O99.210', 'E66.9', 'E66.3')
)
AND pr.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ('TS141', 'TS140')
```